# neo4j: what are org.neo4j.driver.types package classes for?

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm eager to figure out the what do `org.neo4j.driver.types` stand for?

This package becomes available with neo4j driver (`org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver`).

Under this package there are classes like `Entity, Node, RelationShip, ...`.

Are those classes intended to be used like some kind of `ORM(OGM)`.

Note: I'm not using neo4j-ogm. I'm only using `org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver` dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm eager to figure out the what do org.neo4j.driver.types stand for?

These are domain objects for `neo4j` DB ... they are needed by driver to store/load data to/from the database. I would say they are similar to classes like 'ResultSet` for JDBC.

The driver needs these classes to "explain" a write operation to `neo4j` and to "enterpret" the response.